# Converting JSON data into an object or array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch the content from a URL and it gives the following result. The problem is that I am unable to convert it to an array or object. I have checked other queries of similar kind and tried on them as well but I do not understand why this is not being done!

```
[{
"Coupon_ID": "IW12390",
"Campaign_ID": "353",
"Campaign_Name": "Dominos",
"Title": "Get 10% Off on INR 400",
"Description": "Get 10% Off on INR 400 &amp; Above. Valid for online order only. This code is not valid on Simply Veg, Simply N-Veg Pizzas, and Combos.",
"Category": "Food &amp; Beverages",
"Type": "Coupon",
"Type_Value": "DOM10",
"Tracking_URL": "http:\/\/tracking.icubeswire.com\/aff_c?offer_id=353&amp;aff_id=18753",
"Added_Date": "2017-02-01",
"Expiry_Date": "2017-02-07"
},{
"Coupon_ID": "IW12392",
"Campaign_ID": "2269",
"Campaign_Name": "Shoppers Stop",
"Title": "Flat 50% on Fratini Woman",
"Description": "Flat 50% on Fratini Woman only at Shoppers Stop. So Hurry!\r\n\r\n",
"Category": "E-Commerce",
"Type": "Deal",
"Type_Value": "None",
"Tracking_URL": "http:\/\/tracking.icubeswire.com\/aff_c?offer_id=2269&amp;aff_id=18753&amp;url_id=16740",
"Added_Date": "2017-01-05",
"Expiry_Date": "2017-02-01"
}]
```

I have used following curl method to convert them to the above data and i also used file_get_contents which gives the same data as above. I tried to convert it using json_decode but the result is null.

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result ? $result : false;
```

Comment: Tag your question with PHP

Comment: so you are saying `$result` is a string containing the data above? but that `json_decode($result);` returns null? It looks like valid JSON, but maybe something else is happening. Have you checked for error using `json_last_error()`? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: You are right the outcome after json_decode is void. Also There is no error using json_last_error()

Comment: I solved your problem. Select my answer.

Comment: What was your answer though? if json_last_error() is your answer than it didn't show any error. I told in one of my comments that it selected the case JSON_ERROR_NONE. It was not found by json_last_error(). I jumped to conclusion that there is something wrong with the JSON data itself. I thanked for your efforts and time. But the credit goes to none. It was my mistake I didn't take notice of the API returned value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$timeout = 30

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($result, true)
```

Comment: The problem is to convert them to object or array and not the json data itself. JSON data is coming after the curl process.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Use `json_last_error()` to determine what is going on. **After** `json_decode`

Comment: case JSON_ERROR_NONE

Comment: That means the decoding succeded. Inspect the result of `json_decode` with `var_dump`

Comment: I figured something. There was something at the very end of the json decoded data. It closed with ` },] `. And that was the real issue. Thanks @arboreal84 for your valuable time.

Comment: Select it as answer then.

Answer (score 0):

For array : `json_decode($response, true);`

For Object: `json_decode($response);`

Answer (score 0):

The json data was quite long in about 17839 lines long. I couldn't trace what's wrong with json_decode but the error was a badly formatted data from JSON API. It was closing with },]. The comma after curly bracket was the real issue due to which it was not being decoded.